# Error while installing Jupyternotebook through pip

Tags: pip, jupyter

I am getting the following error while installing Jupyternotebook through pip in **Windows 10**. Kindly provide some workaround. Please find the complete output at https://pastebin.com/vxvAtr6S
`C:\Users\prave>echo %PATH% C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\bin;C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin;C:\Program Files\Crucial\Crucial Storage Executive;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\lib;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\FAHClient;C:\Users\prave\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.1\bin;;C:\MinGW\bin;`

Comment: Please post the output of `gcc --version`, and the value of your PATH environment variable

Comment: Request you to check the output at https://pastebin.com/6YtenGF7

Answer (score 0):

> `distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

This line clearly says it, you have to download Microsof Visual C++ 14.0 or greater from the given address.

Comment: Thank You for the advice. I installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools but nowing facing another error. Request you to please check the log at https://pastebin.com/vxvAtr6S .

Comment: @PraveenKumar pooh, a difficult case ... Please tell me where you installed the build tools, and post the output of `echo %PATH%`.

Comment: Thank You for continual support.. I installed the build tools @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools... Pl find Output of `echo %PATH%` @ https://pastebin.com/WRn3ASTv

Comment: @PraveenKumar The pastebin link is broken (displays `Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it`), could you please just add the output to your question ?

Comment: Sorry.. I just made the pastebin public @ https://pastebin.com/WRn3ASTv. Also added the output in the question.

Comment: @PraveenKumar ok, it's clear now : there must be a folder named `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\bin`. You have to add that to your PATH variable.